# Calcular números muy grandes C++

Tags: c++, factorial

hay alguna manera de poder calcular números gigantes en c++ sin la necesidad de instalar librerías extras? intenté instalar la librería GMP para calcular 100!, sin embargo no tuve éxito. quedo atento a respuestas :)

Comment: Solo puedes trabajar cómodamente con números de hasta 64 bits en un procesador moderno. Tal vez el compilador implemente un tipo de 128 bits, pero será más lento ya que las implementaciones para números más grandes son en software. Mejor cuéntanos cuáles son los pasos que seguiste para utilizar la librería así podemos ayudarte a que funcione.

Comment: El valor de `100!` es de magnitud `10^157`. No hay forma de representar esa magnitud usando la librería estándar de C++, que tiene una capacidad de representación de hasta `2^64 -1`. La pregunta es, ¿para qué quieres calcular `100!`? No creo que nadie preste atención al valor generado. Toma en cuenta que a partir de cierta cantidad, la mayoría de dígitos serán ceros. Existen algoritmos eficientes que toman en cuenta esto. Creo que podrías apuntar en esa dirección si hiciera falta. Saludos

Comment: Si no quieres instalar una librería externa para números grandes, debes desarrollar tu propia librería para números grandes. Predigo que no será más fácil. Tal vez quieres probar [Boost.Multiprecision](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html).

Comment: Si solo necesitas manipular cantidades mayores a `2^64 - 1` te recomendaría indagar en la web acerca del uso de una clase para almacenar grandes cantidades de dígitos, esto sobre-cargando operadores aritméticos etc... y guardando los valores en vectores de caracteres y punteros.